# Functional way to accumulate within a Unit function in Kotlin?

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I'm trying to force myself to employ functional programming in Kotlin, and wherever possible, avoid using mutable vars.  Ordinarily, for an *ad hoc* test for a unit-returning function, I'd just `println()` something inside the function to see if it's working right.  But for this test, I need to accumulate a string and then ultimately use `assertEquals(...)`.

As usual, I found myself declaring a `var` in the enclosing scope and using `+=` to accumulate into it.  **Is there a more functional way to do this by passing/chaining a function and eliminating the mutable var?**  Here's some simplified but illustrative code:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachFrom(beg:Int, act:(T)->Unit) {
  var i=0;  if (beg>=0) for (e in this) if (i++ >= beg) act(e)
}

fun main(args:Array<String>) {
  val l = listOf("zero", "one", "two", "three", "four")

  // print-to-screen test
  l.forEachFrom(2){print("$it-")};  println()
  // output:  two-three-four-

  // accumulate-in-var test
  var s = ""
  l.forEachFrom(2){s += "$it-"};  println(s)
  // output:  two-three-four-

  // Is there a purely functional way, without declaring a mutable var?
  // val s = l.forEachFrom(2){accumulator???("$it-")}
  // - OR -
  // val s = l.forEachFrom(2).accumulator???("$it-")
  // println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to do the same with only kotlin-stdlib and retain the semantics of the code (i.e. iterate only once) is to [convert the `Iterable<T>` to `Sequence<T>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) and use the [`.drop(n)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/drop.html) extension:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEachFrom(beg: Int, act: (T) -> Unit) =
    if (beg >= 0)
        asSequence().drop(beg).forEach(act) else
        Unit
```

---

**UPD:** After discussing the overall question, we came up with another approach.

When you have a custom higher-order function that iterates over the items and only accepts a callback but does not return anything, you can wrap that custom iteration logic into a `Sequence<T>` by using [`buildSequence { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/build-sequence.html) and passing `yield(it)` as the callback:

```
val sequenceFromCustomFunction = buildSequence {
    l.forEachFrom(2) { yield(it) }
}
```

This allows you to work with this sequence in functional style and, in particular, fold the sequence:

```
val s = sequenceFromCustomFunction.fold("") { acc, it -> acc + it + "-" }
```

Comment: Thanks... I probably should have come up with a better forEachFrom example.  :) I'm not trying to improve that function, but more trying to understand if one can accumulate a test string within a Unit-returning function in a purely functional way -- without using a `var` in the enclosing scope?  I have a bunch of more complicated `Unit`-returning functions that I need to write tests for.  It's more of an exercise to stretch my mind about whether there's no good alternative to `var s` here.

Comment: @sirksel, basically, accumulating state in functional style is usually done with the *fold* idiom (there's a [`fold` extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) in Kotlin).

Comment: @sirksel, here's an example implementation of the function above with `fold`: [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/20f7985c79f746e91312e375de571dbb)

Comment: You can make the accumulator type as complex as you need, e.g. use a `data` class with a property for each value that you need to accumulate.

Comment: what I couldn't figure out is how to use `fold` with a function returning Unit.  In other words, assume I can't change `forEachFrom`. If the function returned a value, I'd know how to apply fold or reduce or what not by chaining. Is there a way to use a lambda in the `act` block (purely separate from modifying the base function being tested) that employs the fold concept but without referencing a var in the enclosing scope? If there is, I just couldn't get the syntax right.

Comment: @sirksel I'm not sure it's exactly what you want, but you can make another sequence using your custom function for iteration (with `buildSequence { ... }`, which uses coroutines) and then fold it: [(gist)](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/0307c90ddc85c5ff68093ee9e25e79be)

Comment: Your suggestion has me thinking down a new path - thanks!  It won't be simpler than string accumulation with a var, but it's teaching me something about functional programming.  Only problem is I'm getting `error: suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` pointing at the `yield(it)` in your gist.  I don't understand it enough to know why...

Comment: That looks strange, here's a demo that compiles and works just fine: [(runnable demo)](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/UserProjects/j6ltpti7sboo3cps1p0dr1khin/9qetmjie7ck2ruivp13g3hhmh8)